# Alternative expression for $\sin(z)$ on contour

Tags: complex-analysis

Not sure if I am on the right path with this. Question is: let $\gamma$ be the line segment from z=0 to z=i. Find an alternative expression for $\sin(z)$ when z is on $\gamma$ that DOES NOT involve the sine function.

I tried writing $\sin(z)$ as $\frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i}$ and parameterising the contour $\gamma$ as $z=it$ where $0\le t\le 1$. 
This gives $\sin(z)=\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}$ for $0 \le t \le 1$.

The question doesn't ask for a value, just an alternative expression. Feedback? Just need to know if that is a good approach or if there is another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only two I can think of:

The formal power series for the sine:
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{k}{t}^{2\,k+1}}{
 \left( 2\,k+1 \right) !}}
$$

And:

$$-{ i\operatorname{sinh}} \left( it \right) $$

As far as to the specifics of your question I will leave it to you to muck around with, but if the only requisite were to state something equivalent without specifically stating the sine function, these would be my considerations.

Comment: Thanks, hadn't considered rearranging into sinh. There was a follow-up question which asked for an upper bound on e^sin(z) along the same contour, using the alternative expression for sin(z) above. I assumed it would require the ML Lemma but couldn't make it work easily with my expression. I'll give it a go with these.